# check if component rendered from sibling component

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

**Description:**

I am trying to load markers onto a map that correspond with the `FullAddresses` on a grid store. I am using `Extjs 4.1.3` and the `grid` and `gmap` components.

**Problem:**

How can I check if the grid rendered from the scope of the gmap? I'm trying to place a `load` event on the grid from inside the gmap. Doing this because the gmap needs the store data and I need to know if the grid is rendered before trying to query the store. The store takes about 2 seconds to load so the map and containing panel is finished rendering way before the grid is initialize and the store is populated.

I am creating the `grid` right after `gmap`. I don't mind waiting for the store to load (`store.on('load')`), I'm trying to figure out how to access the grid when it's rendered.

**Question:**

Is there a way that I can access the grid component when loaded/rendered? I know I can put a `afterrender` after the store is loaded or the grid is rendered, but I have a code restriction that disallows that for now.

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('grid_id'); 
// grid returns undefined because the gmap finished sooner
```

I can mimic this type of functionality with the `jQuery.on()` function:

```
$('already rendered').on('event', 'element listened for', function () {});
```

Comment: When you are creating grid? You can create gird and gmap component at the same time and then load data into grid. Grid does not wait with rendering for moment when data is loaded. If you need perform action after data is loaded use `load` event handler on store. If you need wait after elements representing Store items has been rendered in grid, use grid's `viewready` event handler.

Comment: I am creating the `grid` right after `gmap`. I don't mind waiting for the store to load, I'm trying to figure out how to access the grid when it's rendered.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. If you want to know when the grid is rendered, use the `afterrender` event, that's exactly what it's there for. Also, what does the store load have to do with the grid rendering?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to check if the grid is rendered FROM the gmap scope. EDIT: I edited the question!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they are actually siblings:

```
var grid = map.next(); // or map.prev();
grid.getStore().on('load', function() {
    console.log('...');
});
```

There are plenty of methods for navigating components, I'd suggest you look at the docs to choose the appropriate one:

- [`up`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-up)
- [`next`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-next)
- [`prev`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-prev)
- [`down`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-down)
- [`child`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-child)
- [`query`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-query)

Comment: but how do I know if the `grid` is rendered and able to get accessed?

Comment: I think you're getting confused. A store can load and have data in it totally independent of a grid. The status of the grid being rendered has nothing to do with the store load.

Comment: I know. in the config of the gmap, I have `grid.getStore().on('load')` but how can I get the `grid` if I don't know if it has been rendered yet. Because `var grid = Ext.getCmp('grid')` is undefined because it's not build yet.

Comment: Again, I think you're getting confused. A component can be created and not rendered. It's not really useful to keep enumerating all the possibilities of what you may be doing, post a fiddle.

Comment: the answer is not one of `sibling` navigation.. I don't even know how you got that... maybe I'll post a fiddle tonight if no one answers

Comment: You've essentially posted no code, asking "how do I make my code work". How do you expect anyone to answer? At least post your your attempt.